# Probability question regarding $5$ dice.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question is - Poker is played by simultaneously rolling $5$ dice. Show that $P(\text{two pair}) = 0.2315$.

So, what I did is: First, I select two dice in $\binom52$ ways and then select another two dice in $\binom32$ ways. Then, I select two numbers in $\binom62$ ways and assigned it to the two pair of dice and then select one another number in $\binom41$ ways and assigned it to the remaining one dice. So, I get the answer as $P(\text{two pair})=\frac{\binom52\cdot \binom32\cdot\binom62\cdot\binom41}{6^5}$.

I got it correct but after thinking a little, I am a little confused. Let's name the five dices as A, B, C, D and E. So, first, we select two dice, let's say A and B. Then again we select two dice C and D. Then, we select two numbers, let's say $1$ and $2$. Then we select another number, let's say $3$. According to what I calculated earlier, I am assigning $1$ and $2$ to (A,B) and (C,D). So, that means (A,B) can be assigned $1$ and (C,D) can be assigned $2$ or (A,B) can be assigned $2$ and (C,D) can be assigned $1$. That is, if we write it in the form of ordered tuples with $5$ coordinates for $5$ dices, we get that $(1,1,2,2,3)$ and $(2,2,1,1,3)$ are same if we are doing the calculation that I did. Why are we considering them as same?  We consider $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ different when we deal with two dice. But here I think I am considering it same. Can anyone please explain. My explanation is a bit messy, please let me know if you need any clarification about my question.

Thanks!

Comment: Because you are choosing the order ahead of time. You did not say, let's choose four dice to be the two pairs. You decided specifically that you would have one pair, then a second pair. That takes care of orders of the values among the pairs.

Comment: Because you didn't count two ways of assigning numbers to A, so there's no reason to divide by two.  If you are a bit more explicit, it will be easier to see.  After we choose two numbers, assign the higher one to A, and the lower one to B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intuition for two pair and one pair in poker dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1957497) or [Probability of two pairs of poker dice and letter arrangement](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2278182)

Comment: @InterstellarProbe So, here the four dice are chosen in two ways - one instance may be (A,B) and then (C,D) or (C,D) then (A,B), so we have to divide it by $2$ which cancels the effect of the orders of the values among the pairs. Right?

Comment: You are choosing two dice, then two dice. You may get (A,B), then (C,D), or you may get (C,D), then (A,B). Either way, you are assigning the values one way (either you assign the 1 then the 2 or vise versa. You did not choose an order, so you must assign the values in a single order). Thus, if you use saulspatz's method for choosing the order (you always assign the higher number first), then you get: $(A,B)(C,D)(E) (2,2,1,1,3)$. Later, then you choose $(C,D)(A,B)(E)$, you get $(2,2,1,1,3)$. So, you wind up with the same result as had you chosen $(A,B,C,D,E): (1,1,2,2,3)$.

Comment: In other words, you are fixing the order you are assigning the values, and only permuting the order that the dice are assigned values.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Thank you very much, I got it.